# Best solution for automated emails based on unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

There are 6 fields in the table called eblasts. ID, message, drop_dead, warning1, warning2 and due_date. drop_dead, due_date, warning1 and warning2 are all unix timestamps. I need to send an email if that time has past. So I want to look up the drop_dead date from the DB (which will be the latest time an email should be sent) see how it compares to the current time. If its past drop_dead then do nothing. If its before drop_dead then it needs to send an emails.

In that email I need to cross reference another 2 other tables (contacts and companies).  The contacts are tied to each company via a company_id column in the contacts table (there can be multiple contacts for 1 company). I also have another table which has whether or not they have responded (eblast_id, company_id, timestamp). Only the ones that have not responded need to get emailed.

Make sense? Any ideas on how to make this work or where I should start? My brain is fried from trying to figure this out.

This is what I go so far ... just help putting the pieces together/filling in the missing spots.

```
$timestamp = time();

$drop_dead = mysql_query("SELECT drop_dead, ID, warning_1 FROM eblasts") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $last_time[$row[1]] = $row[0];
        $last_time[$row[1]] = $row[2];
};

print_r($last_time);

foreach($last_time as $key => $value) {
    if($timestamp < $value){
        $final_email[] = $key;
        };
    };

if(){
    $find_franchise = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM franchisees") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($find_franchise, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $franchise_id[] = $row[0];  
    }
    $find_responded = mysql_query("SELECT franchise_id FROM participation");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($find_responded, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $part_franchise[] = $row[0];    
    }
    $to_email_franchise_id = array_diff($franchise_id, $part_franchise);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

-Adam

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward, Adam. Where specifically are you running into problems?

Comment: I edited with some additional code which hopefully will help as a starting off point for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the UNIX_TIMESTAMP MySQL function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

In a nutshell:

```
SELECT * FROM `eblasts` WHERE `drop_dead` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() );
```

The downside of this method though is that the timestamp will be re-evaluated on each query, and it'll result in a lot useless system calls.

This would be more efficient:

```
SET @cutoff = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() );
SELECT * FROM `eblasts` WHERE `drop_dead` < @cutoff;
```

However, if your original Unix timestamps (those in the DB) come directly from PHP, I would suggest that you calculate your cutoff using the `time()` function of PHP instead, especially if your MySQL server isn't running on the same physical machine. That way, you'll avoid sending the message too late if the MySQL server date/time (or timezone) isn't the same as your web server's.